# Termine unico per fornitore, costruttore e assistente tecnico

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Sto implementando un'anagrafica unica dei **fornitori**, **costruttori** e **assistenti tecnici**.

Questo vuol dire che un fornitore potrà anche essere un costruttore e/o un assistente tecnico.

Vorrei trovare una voce che riassuma queste tre categorie.

Al momento, infatti, la voce di menu indica ***Anagrafica fornitori*** ma, appunto questa sarà arricchita da queste nuove figure, per cui ho bisogno di un termine che raggruppi tutti i concetti.

Non me ne viene in mente alcuno, né tanto meno cercando sul web ho avuto idee.

Comment: Quali sono invece esempi di categorie che _non_ sono incluse? Potrebbe andare bene, per esempio, qualcosa come “collaboratori”? O è troppo generale e include anche figure che rientrano in altre categorie?

Comment: No, collaboratori mi sembra più "personale" come termine, nel senso che indica più la persona, mentre nel mio caso l'anagrafica è più aziendale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Io propongo l'espressione ***Anagrafica mandatari***.

Ho avuto una necessità simile alla tua per un progetto in ambito informatico in cui c'era un'*anagrafica contraenti* che comprendeva il *committente* di un lavoro (cioè chi richiede la prestazione) e il *mandatario* di un lavoro (cioè chi esegue la prestazione).

La prestazione da parte del mandatario può essere di natura diversa, cioè la fornitura di materiale, l'assemblaggio di un apparato oppure la fornitura di un servizio di assistenza tecnica.

Quindi penso che la parola mandatario possa racchiudere fornitori, costruttori e assistenti tecnici e l'anagrafica mandatari sia il loro elenco strutturato.

Comment: Ciao, sì, mi pare interessante come termine e rispecchia in buona sostanza le mie esigenze (anche a me è una applicazione in ambito informatico).

Comment: Non dovrebbe essere "anagrafica mandatari" con la minuscola? Cioè, questo uso della maiuscola non è qualcosa che si fa in inglese ma non in italiano?

Comment: Essendo un titolo da mettere su un menù di un’applicazione software potrebbe essere sensato mostrare _Anagrafica mandatari_.

Comment: @abarisone: Ti andrebbe di scriverlo in questo modo (cioè, in quello del tuo commento) nella risposta?